# AjaxMin not running on CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage when using MSDeploy to remote server

Tags: visual-studio, msdeploy, ajaxmin

I'm trying to get my `JS` and `CSS` files to be automatically minified when publishing our `Web App`, but it only seems to work on a `File System` publish not a web deploy; using the target `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage` in a `.pubxml` file.

I've tried running on different targets but the same result.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="AjaxMin" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\lib\AjaxMinTask.dll" />
  <Target Name="CompressJsAndCss" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">
    <ItemGroup>
      <JS Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.js" Exclude="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.min.js" />
      <CSS Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.css" Exclude="$(_PackageTempDir)\**\*.min.css" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Compressing JavaScript and CSS files in $(PublishDir)..." Importance="high" />
    <AjaxMin JsKnownGlobalNames="jQuery,$" JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js" CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".css" />
  </Target>
```

I'd expect it to minify the files in the temporary package folder, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to solve the problem. 
I had to find the right target and folders to do this on:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="AjaxMin" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\lib\AjaxMinTask.dll" />
  <Target Name="CompressJsAndCss" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForAspNetCompileMerge">
    <ItemGroup>
      <JS Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\**\*.js" Exclude="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\**\*.min.js" />
      <CSS Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\**\*.css" Exclude="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\**\*.min.css" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Compressing JavaScript and CSS files in $(IntermediateOutputPath)..." Importance="high" />
    <AjaxMin JsKnownGlobalNames="jQuery,$" JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js" CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".css" />
  </Target>
```

Now after the first copy, it will minify the files and use those going forward